# Customization of text in SuiteBar of SharePoint 2019?

Tags: branding, 2019, suitebar

In SharePoint 2019, the left-hand side of the Suite Bar contains the text "SharePoint" - is there a way to customize that text?
[Branding SharePoint: The New Normal](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Branding-SharePoint-The-New-Normal/ba-p/241855)  does not cover this, and the property "SuiteNavBrandingText" (see [SharePoint 2016 How to Change SuitBar’s Text PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34202.sharepoint-2016-how-to-change-suitbars-text-powershell.aspx)) does not work either.
I would like to do it in powershell, so that e.g. no CSS needs to be updated.

Comment: Is there any workaround/solution identified for this kind of requirement, I think such type of requirement many customers may be keep asking for Customization of text in SuiteBar.
Searching for same solution in SP 2019...

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

$WebApp= Get-SPWebApplication "http://webapp"
$WebApp.SuiteNavBrandingText = "Name" (Sharepoint to be replaced )
$webapp.Update()

Comment: That's setting the property "SuiteNavBrandingText" as already mentioned in the question. That approach does not work for SharePoint 2019 :-(